# expected primary-expression before 'else'

Tags: c++

I have an emergency here. This homework is due tomorrow for my CP 1 class. We have to make a simple dice game. If you get doubles of the same number, then good things happen. Here is the function:

```
void Doubles();       //prototype for the function Doubles()
//pre: n/a
//post: Plays a simple dice game with the user

void Doubles()
{
    //variables declared to store dice values
    int DieOne, DieTwo, PlayerSame, ComputerSame;

    cout<<"\nLET'S PLAY DOUBLES!!!\n"<<endl;
    srand ( time(NULL) );         //initialize random seed

    DieOne = rand()%6 + 1;
    DieTwo = rand()%6 + 1;

    cout<<"\nYour first die is a "<<DieOne;
    cout<<"\nYour second die is a "<<DieTwo;
    if(DieOne == DieTwo)
    {
       PlayerSame = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        PlayerSame = 0;
    }

    DieOne = rand()%6 + 1;
    DieTwo = rand()%6 + 1;

    cout<<"\n\nThe computer's first die is a "<<DieOne;
    cout<<"\nThe computer's second die is a "<<DieTwo;
    if(DieOne == DieTwo)
    {
        ComputerSame = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        ComputerSame = 0;
    }

    if(PlayerSame == 1 && ComputerSame == 0)
    {
        cout<<"\n\nYou win! Your dice are the same and the "
            <<"computer's dice aren't!";
    }
        else if(PlayerSame == 1 && ComputerSame == 1)
        {
            cout<<"\n\nYou tied! Your dice are the same and the "
                <<"computer's dice are the same!";
        }
        else if(PlayerSame == 0 && ComputerSame == 1)
        {
            cout<<"\n\nYou lost! Your dice are not the same, and the "
                <<"computer's dice are!";
    else
    {
        cout<<"\n\nNeither you nor the computer had dice that matched, "
            <<"so you both lose!";
    }
}
```

So why, wen I run this, am I getting the compiler error stated in the title? the primary expression is right there! The "else" it's referring to is the last one there. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you have a question about a compiler error, you should give the full error message that the compiler gave you, including line numbers.

Comment: An editor that does brace matching, syntax highlighting, or code formatting would also have helped you catch this error. For example, vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the brace, as has been pointed out, but the flaw comes from not being able to look at the code indentation correctly and not being able to clearly see the error.  The indentation on the else if's is indented one more than the if, and if this were not the case, you would quickly see the missing brace, but, as formatted, it is more easily missed, although I did not even read the whole post before looking at the code and spotting the missing brace myself (I have a lot of legacy code which I maintain that has bad indentation that I have been fixing for years, and this is a common type of formatting error that leads to this specific problem..  Proper formatting would lead to the spotting of this type of error much more quickly, especially in programmers that have not been programming for a long time and are not seasoned to fix the formatting in their head as they read through before looking at code specifics.

Jay

Answer (score 2):

you forgot the closing brace for the block after the second `else if`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are missing a brace `}` after `<<"computer's dice are!";` line.

Doesn't your compiler tell you the line number where it sees the error?

Answer (score 1):

PLease add the closing brace before the else.

```
else if(PlayerSame == 0 && ComputerSame == 1)
{
    cout<<"\n\nYou lost! Your dice are not the same, and the "
        <<"computer's dice are!";

}
    else
    {
        cout<<"\n\nNeither you nor the computer had dice that matched, "
            <<"so you both lose!";
    }
```